# How to make multiple instances of my WPF application use the same data?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, appdomain, multiple-instances

I have a WPF application that generates and uses data (like statistics) by binded GUI elements, which are saved and loaded on the harddrive on certain occassions.

*I want the user to be able to run multiple instances of the application at the same time.*
Therefore I want all instances of this app to use the same data processing classes to be able to see any changes to the data in all instances of my app and to prevent overwriting files or using old data.

I know every start of my executable starts another process by default. I have heard about AppDomains but know almost nothing about them and I am not sure if that's the right direction.

What would be the best way to do this?

EDIT:
People seem to be ignoring what i want and try to push me in other directions.
So let me clear this up, I HAVE to be able to use multiple instances because in my app the user can select different profiles on which the data generated depends and my whole GUI is build on it. The generated statistics and logging data must not be stored individually for each profile.

Comment: You should probably use a database. Syncing File-Access can be an issue; ie, if one application writes and creates a lock, the other has to wait. However, you can get notified upon change in the other instances using FileWatcher.

Comment: What problem are you running into - what isn't working?

Comment: Why don't you use, instead two applications, tabs or any other control to show the data twice? You will solve probably tons of problems with syncing files and so one.

Comment: @SlapY Using a database is not an option unfortunately

Comment: @SlapY why isnt it an option

Comment: You could create some kind of data host application, which is started at application start and handles data access

Comment: Best way is still to use a database. File-based one, such as SQLite, will do. That way you still have single file on your drive, but you can reliably read and write to that from multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a WCF Service. There is a lot of information available on this. Maybe start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WCF_Data_Services

Comment: Thank you, i will take s look at this